# How to show/hide default product tabs?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

In my client's theme there is some bug, that doesn't show sale price in archive if product is variable. With simple products all is fine. We found, that if we change variable product to simple, save regular and sale price in general tab, and then make the product variable again, the price appears in the archive.
So they ask me to make the General tab visible for variable products.

Yes, it would be right to find what's causing this bug, but they don't give me FTP, and this is a child theme, and their priority is to make it quick, not to make it right. I have to do what they ask.

The general tab generally exists even or a variable product, it's just hidden.
So I need to make it visible for variable products too.
What I already tried

```
function art_added_tabs( array $tabs ): array {

    $tabs['general'] = [
        'label'    => 'General', 
        'target'   => 'general_product_data',  
        'class'    => [ 'show_if_variable show_if_simple' ],  
        'priority' => 5, // 
    ];

    return $tabs;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'art_added_tabs', 10, 1 );
```

And that

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', function($tabs) {
    $tabs['general'] = [
        'label' => __('General', 'txtdomain'),
        'target' => 'general_product_data',
        'class' => ['show_if_variable show_if_simple'],
        'priority' => 25
    ];
    return $tabs;
});
```

And that

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'misha_product_data_tabs' );
function misha_product_data_tabs( $tabs ){
 
    $tabs['general']['class'][] = 'show_if_variable show_if_simple';
    return $tabs;
 
}
```

That too

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'show_hide_general_tab' );
function show_hide_general_tab() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showHideGeneralTab() {           
                jQuery('li.general_options.general_tab').show();             
                jQuery('li.general_options.general_tab').attr('style','display:block!important'); 
                jQuery('li.general_options.general_tab').removeClass('hide_if_grouped');  
            }     
        
        // runs the script when the page loads
        showHideGeneralTab();
    </script>
    <?php }
```

I think I miss something, how to make it visible?

Comment: You can see the scripts responsible for hiding - woocommerce/assets/js/admin/meta-boxes-product.js  you have to load your script afte the execution of this one. If you check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/ you can see $deps where you specify when to load - wc-admin-product-meta-boxes-js and use admin_enqueue_scripts action to load it in backend.

Comment: "Yes, would be right to find what't causing this bug, but they don't give me ftp, and this is a child theme, and their priority is to make it quick, not to make it right. " I would just pass on this type of clients where they think they are oversmart since you have access to everything even with just theme editor....

Comment: Yes, they are....strange, but that one already payed once, so if they want quick, but not right ways - "ok, as you wish if you pay"

Comment: thanks for the link, admin_enqueue_scripts paste before my last script?

Comment: that is your action hook that will load the script for backend. doesnt matter where you place it. wp_enqueue_script is the important part where you specify when to load your script. add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','test'); function test() { wp_enqueue_script('myscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/js/myscript.js',array('wc-admin-product-meta-boxes')); }

Comment: Here is where its loaded - https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-admin-class-wc-admin-assets.html at row 234.

Comment: would be a problem - without ftp I can't create a new js file. and there's no js files in child theme. I planned to add the single script in functions.php as in the last example.

Comment: You can create and write to a file with php ( that was my point of clients being smart). In your case i would go with css over js - li.general_options.general_tab.hide_if_grouped, .options_group.pricing.show_if_simple.show_if_external.hidden {display:block !important;}

Comment: who could think! yes, css helped with all that hooks together. classes made selector more 'big', and then styles had bigger priority. stypid clients and stupidest way to solve

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'show_pricing_option');

function show_pricing_option() {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $("#general_product_data .pricing").show();
        });
        </script>
    <?php

}
```

Place this code in your active theme functions.php file, this will run on the `woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data`

Comment: sadly didn't help too((